# Python 3.4 Import a list to function

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code:

```
list1 = []

def funct1(list1):
    numb1 = *random number generated*
    list1 = list1.append(numb1)
    print (list1)

funct1()
```

I am looking to append the number to the list. When I run the function for the second time, the number is in the list and another number will be added to the list.

Comment: Nope. You are not iterating anywhere in this code. So you will not get that error.

Comment: What exactly is the *problem*? It's a bad idea to use a list like that, but it will work.

Comment: @thefourtheye changed the question

Comment: @jonrsharpe it doesnt work, it prints none

Comment: Yes, because `.append` returns `None` - it's an in-place operation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, well in my case, I am looking to append the number to the list. When I run the function for the second time, the number is in the list and another number will be added to the list

Comment: ...OK. What's your *question*? Just don't assign the result of the `append` back to `list1`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can I make sure that each time I run the function, the random number will be appened to the list1!

Comment: Just **do that**, `.append` it. What level of assurance do you need, exactly?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe It prints None instead of the list when I run the script

Comment: @jonrsharpe OMG! Okay I just understood, indead of {list1 = list1.append(numb1)} I should do {list1.append(numb1)}! You can write it in the answer if you want me to accept it. Thanks man

Comment: this is the 3rd time today that I see a post where an OP writes a_list = a_list.append(x), where the hell did they all get this from??? Is there a really bad python for beginners tutorial somewhere on the web which they all fell on??!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted fails with

```
TypeError: funct1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'list1'
```

Since the list is a global (not especially good), it should not be passed.
As people said, do not rebind the global name.

```
from random import random

list1 = []

def funct1():
    list1.append(random())
    print (list1)

funct1()
funct1()
```

prints

```
[0.8260317762745185]
[0.8260317762745185, 0.341112710213196]
```